# For pass to function is it worth packing the matrix and its dimension in a struct or is it OK to use additional parameters?

Tags: c, struct, matrix

Here is a matrix declared as pointer to an array of pointers to rows.
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/609809/Screenshots/-6mz.png]
*(source: [Numerical Recipes in C](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php))*

What is the better way to pass this matrix to a function along with its dimensions?

```
void printMatrix(float **matrix, int rows, int cols);
```

Or pack it in a struct

```
struct Matrix { 
  int rows, cols; 
  int **data; 
};
```

and pass a pointer to the struct?

```
void printMatrix(struct Matrix *m);
```

Comment: It probably doesn't make any practical difference for most ABIs.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Just want to know different possibilities in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single perfect method. In the [appropriate chapter of c-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc3.html) you can see 5 methods and their comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways work, however, the approach using a struct is a bit "easier" to use. You (or whoever will use this) won't have to worry about passing the correct size as well and it isn't required to organize it at all. You just handle one struct or one logical object. If you split everything up, you'll have to handle the data as well as the meta data yourself (i.e. storying/passing data and dimensions).

Is there a downside using the struct? Not that I know of (other than having to handle one more pointer). However there is one huge advantage: Using the struct you could use a function wanting data and meta data separated as well (by passing the struct elements rather than a pointer to the struct). This isn't that easy the other way around.

As for "is it worth it?" considering "should I do it for organisaiton?": Do it, if the grouping is logical. Lots of windows APIs work with structs that way, but I'm not a real fan of them, if the grouping isn't logical or it creates additional "pains". In other words: Don't group your parameters into a struct, if they're not related or if the user most likely wouldn't have them in that form (i.e. they're grouped for this call only).

Edit:

As an example:

- I'd group your example data, as width and height belong to the matrix data and they're related (plus they might be used in other functions the same way).
- However, I wouldn't group parameters such as this: `write_log(LOG_INFO, "All data has been processed");` Adding a struct here would add complexity that isn't required. It's very likely that this group of data won't be used elsewhere and makes calling the function more complicated (as you'll have to create the struct first).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of optimization, I would consider simply passing the struct by value. i.e.

```
void printMatrix(struct Matrix m);
```

without the pointer. It's a very small data structure and the processor might just store this top-level data in the cache. The compiler and processor may be able to optimize access to this top-level data.

Then again, it might do nothing or even make it worse. Optimization can be a black art.

(And don't forget that if you make changes to the top-level Matrix struct, then you'll need to return it somehow). So maybe this should only be considered in place of `const struct Matrix *m`.